# Fatal error (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

It is my shared hosting running 3 websites. Just from yesterday, all of those are giving the same error.

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/user/... ...
>   /index.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')
>   in Unknown on line 0

I have changed nothing during this time.

I found some answers about this error, but they are mostly need root access to settings. I do not have root access. Please suggest me what can I do.

Note: the public_html folder has permission set to 750, I tried using 755 but the error is same. Can I keep it 750?

Comment: That isn't an error. It's a diagnostic message that follows an error.

Comment: how can I find the actual error?

Comment: Look at your web server's and/or PHP's error logs, which you hopefully have access to. If it's shared, managed hosting, contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Checked error log. Last entry is 25-May-2017 02.25 AM, while the site was functional. Nothing after that.

Comment: just installed a fresh wp and it is showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the include path of your php installation was updated. This can happen if the php was updated by the hosting company.

The error message is:

```
"Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/user/... ... /index.php'"
```

It means the file index.php cannot be found. Does this file exist?. Is the include statement using a relative path?

You should mention the error to your hosting company

Comment: They asked to commentout the open_basedir in php.ini file. But it does not work. I checked the file exists and the require path is like this, require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );

Comment: Well I mean does the index.php file exist at the path mentioned in the error ?. The path mentioned in the error is: /home/user/... .../index.php

Comment: Yes. Today I removed the joomla site from the host and other sites, wp and drupal started work. Dont know why. The joomla site is working on another host without any modification.